# Add Jpanel to a Jscrollbar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm trying to add a Jpanel to a JscrollBAr but when i run java it's not working. It's a RadioButton with a question. Can you help me please ?
this is my class jpanel :

```
public class yesnoPanel extends JPanel {
private JPanel quest;
private JPanel answ;
public yesnoPanel(String q){
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    JRadioButton yes = new JRadioButton("yes");
    JRadioButton no = new JRadioButton("no");
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
    JTextArea question = new JTextArea(1,20);
    question.setText(q);
    JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
    pan2.add(question);
    bg.add(yes);
    bg.add(no);
    pan.add(yes);
    pan.add(no);
    this.quest=pan2;
    this.answ=pan;
}
```

I can show them when i use JFrame but not with Jscrollbar
This is my main with the jscrollbar :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame fram = new JFrame();
    yesnoPanel question = new yesnoPanel("are you ok");
    JPanel q = question.getQuestion();
    JPanel a = question.getAnsw();
    JPanel all = new JPanel();
    all.add(q);
    all.add(a);
    yesnoPanel question2 = new yesnoPanel("sure ?");
    JPanel q2 = question2.getQuestion();
    q2.setSize(200,500);
    JPanel a2 = question2.getAnsw();
    JPanel all2 = new JPanel();
    all2.add(q2,BorderLayout.WEST);
    all2.add(a2);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    scroll.setViewportView(all);
    scroll.setVisible(true);
}
```

thanks to all

Comment: In your code, you don't add the JScrollPane to the JFrame anywhere (and also, you don't show if and where the JFrame is made visible). Try to post a minimal, complete example.

Comment: Thank you, so i have to do first a jframe and add my jscrollpane to this jframe ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). @MarkusFischer Good suggestion. Note that `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your last few lines in main method with this to make it work.

```
JPanel master = new JPanel();
master.add(all);
master.add(all2);

JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(master);
scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
scroll.setViewportView(all);
scroll.setVisible(true);

fram.add(scroll);
fram.pack();
fram.setVisible(true);
fram.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Comment: I would recommend you to read this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/. It will help.

Comment: I just fixed your code, but you need to follow a better coding pattern\style.

Comment: Thanks, work great, last question, my all and all2 are both on the same line but i want all2 under all how do i do that?

Comment: `master.setLayout(new BoxLayout(master, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`

Comment: add this below 'JPanel master'.  Read about layouts in swing.